# Tikz: call self defined coordinate of local bounding box

Tags: tikz-pgf

I am drawing a tikz picture with some arrows. There are two separate sets of formations which have to be rotated against each other in a specific way. That's why I am using two `scope`-environments. To draw the paths I used self defined coordinates in relative distance to each other. Now I need to draw an arrow between two points, each of them defined in another `scope`-environment. I tried to use a local bounding box and call the coordinate by refering to it, but it doesn't work. Is there a way to realise this?

Edit: changed name of the bounding box; added image of the desided result; changed coordinate names for better understanding.

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{scope}[local bounding box = bbox, rotate =-7.765, transform shape]
  \node (O) [] at (0,0) {};
  \node (U1) [right of=O, node distance = 10cm] {};
  
  \draw (O.center) [-latex] to (U1.center);
\end{scope}
\begin{scope}[rotate = 5.194, transform shape]
  \node (O) [] at (0,0) {};
  \node (U2) [right of=O, node distance = 9.568cm] {};
  
  \draw (O.center) [-latex] to (U2.center);
  
  \draw (U2.center) [-latex] to (bbox.U1.center);
\end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: desided result]

Comment: Add a hand sketch of the desided result.

Comment: "L.O.center" is wrong. Add "name prefix=L-" to the options of the first scope. And then use "\draw (U2.center) [-latex] to (L-O.center);".

Comment: I added a picture of the result I want. The problem is not about the name prefix, it is that I need a coordinate which is defined in another scope.

Comment: Your code compiles fine just removing `bbox.` in `[…] (bbox.U1.center) […]`

Comment: Thanks. It works now for me as well.  Somehow I didn't think about that.